# JavaScript logical operators questions?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I just don't understand how && and || work. I wrote up a small code to help myself out and it just doesn't make any sense to me. You would click a button and the startGame() would be called.

```
var startGame = function() {
var quizAnswers = {
    name: prompt("What is your name?").toUpperCase(),
    age: prompt("What is your age?"),
    snack: prompt("What is your favorite type of snack out of the following: ice cream, apple, chips, cookies?").toUpperCase()
};

quizAnswers.confirmAge = function () {
        while (isNaN(this.age) === true) {
           this.age = prompt("The age that you entered- " + this.age + " -is not a number. Please enter a number.");
        };
};

quizAnswers.confirmAge();

quizAnswers.confirmSnack = function () {
        while ((this.snack !== "ICE CREAM") && (this.snack !== "APPLE") && (this.snack !== "CHIPS") && (this.snack !== "COOKIES")) {
            this.snack = prompt("The snack you entered- " + this.snack + " -is unrecognized. Please enter: ice cream, apple, chips, or cookies.").toUpperCase();
        };
};

quizAnswers.confirmSnack();
```

It would get name, age, and favorite snack and then check to see if the age is a number and the snack entered is one of the listed options. After messing with the while loop in the confirmSnack function, I figured out how to make it work, which is displayed above. But why is it && and not ||. And is there a way to shorten it like:

```
while (this.snack !== ("ICE CREAM" && "APPLE" && "CHIPS" && "COOKIES")) {
    this.snack = prompt("The snack you entered- " + this.snack + " -is invalid. Please enter: ice cream, apple, chips, or cookies.").toUpperCase();
        };
```

So the questions are to explain why &&(and) is used instead of ||(or) and if there is a way to shorten this code so i don't have to enter "this.snack !==" four times. I'm not an expert so please try to keep it simple.

Comment: Try reading the expressions aloud, using "is different from" for "!==". It should be obvious that "a is different from b, or a is different from c" is not the logic you want, since that lets a be the same as b, as long as it's not also the same as c.

Comment: This isn't related to JavaScript, more like Math and Logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators compare **boolean** values. (Boolean means true/false). That means if you execute `5 == 5 && 6 + 1 == 7` the interpreter does the following things:

1. Evaluate `5 == 5`. The `==` operator returns true if both sides are equal (as you probably know). Since `5 == 5` is `true`, we look at the next value (if it were false, because of short circuit operators, it would return false immediately).
2. Evaluate `6 + 1 == 7`. This is also true, so the returned value is `true`.

The `&&` operator does not compare regular values such as `"ICE CREAM"` (well it does, but it converts it into a boolean value).

Now let's look at the code you provided:

`this.snack !== ("ICE CREAM" && "APPLE" && "CHIPS" && "COOKIES")`

First, the javascript interpreter executes `("ICE CREAM" && "APPLE" && "CHIPS" && "COOKIES")`. Since all of those values are true, the value of that expression is `true`. So this comparison is essentially checking `this.snack !== true`, which is not what you want.

To solve your problem, I would suggest using `indexOf`. This checks if an element is in an array and returns `-1` if there is no element. For example:

```
var validSnacks = ["ICE CREAM", "APPLE", "CHIPS", "COOKIES"];
while (validSnacks.indexOf(this.snack) === -1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The && operator is working just fine. This is actually a question of logic, not javascript.

You are asking the question while the answer is different from ALL of the possible answers.

It could be rewritten with || as the follwing:

```
while (!(this.snack == "ICE CREAM" || this.snack == "APPLE" || this.snack == "CHIPS" || this.snack == "COOKIES"))
```

Notice the `!` operator in the beginning.

A shorter form to write it would be:

```
answers = ["ICE CREAM", "APPLE", "CHIPS", "COOKIES"];
while (answers.indexOf(this.snack) < 0) { ... }
```

Here you define a list of possible answers and you want to accept, and check if the answer is among them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `or(||)`, if *any* of the sub-statements (e.g. this.snack !== "ICE CREAM") evaluate to `true`, the entire statement will be true, causing the prompt to be shown.

On the other hand, using `and(&&)`, *all* of the sub-statements must be true for the entire statement to evaluate as true, which is the behaviour that you want - you only want the prompt to show if snack is not one of the 4 options.

There is no way to shorten the code in the way you suggest. One thing you could do would be to make an array with the 4 options in it and check if that array contains snack.